# Permissions on Content Types?

Tags: permissions, document-library, content-type

I am using sharepoint 2010 and made my own content type that inherits from the page content type. This content type is in a folder called "content types"

I am having a weird problem where if the user does not have "contribute" or higher at the root level they cannot create a page even if the folder that they should be allowed to create pages has contribute.

```
Root level -> read
A specific folder -> contribute or full
```

This will result in them not being able to create a page

```
Root level -> contribute
A specified folder -> does not matter
```

This will result in them being able to create a page.

Answer (score 2):

@chobo2: I think you're mixing some terminology here. My guess is that you mean you've created the Content Type on the root site of the Site Collection and that you've made that Content Type available on a Document Library in a subsite?

Content Types don't exist in "folders"; they are created on the site level and are generally available to that site and all of its subsites. Permissions aren't granted on the Content Type iself, but on the list or library where you make them available for use: List (or Library) Settings / Advanced Settings / Allow management of content types? = Yes. Then you can add whichever Content Type(s) you'd like to be available in the Content Types section of the List/Library Settings.

Comment: @Marc D Anderson - Let me re-explain. In the GUI(All items) there are libraries when I go into one of the libraries(Pages) their are all my files in folders. Each folder has different permission groups associated with them. If I go into one of the folders where I would have "Contribute" Permission and go to the ribbon and click -> New -> Create Page(My content type inherits from page). I will get "accessed denied".  If I go to site actions -> permissions -> go to that group and give them contribute(so I am guessing now they have it at the root level of Pages). I can then create a page.

Comment: That's still hard to follow, but can't you just give them Contribute permissions on the folder in Pages? Or, simply create a different Document Library to hold this special type of "Page"? (I don't think you've said what the name of this Content Type is.)

Comment: Well everything in that document uses this custom type(My Custom Page).So I use this instead of "article page". Each folder in the pages library will have it's own set of user groups and each group will have different permissions on that folder. I am saying that even if I add Group X to Folder A and Group X has contribute permission on Folder A I cannot add a page with "My Custom Page" to that folder(ribbon -> create document -> My custom page). I have to give Group X contribute permission on the Page library level before it allows me to create a page in Folder A.

Comment: So it sounds like you should rethink the architecture based on your business requirements.

Comment: @Marc D Anderson  - So your saying it is not possible to have only people to create pages in folders they have "contribute" or above permissions?

Comment: I'm saying based on what I understand of the problem you are trying to solve, there may be better solutions.

Comment: @Marc D Anderson - Basically this is the problem I am having http://clintoncherry.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/fixing-error-access-denied-error-on-creating-a-new-page-in-moss/ except the steps do not work to resolve it and I cannot see this "create page"

Comment: I think that clintoncherry's post is different. You're trying to segregate permissions in the Pages Document Library by folder; clintoncherry has an issue with users being able to read the page layout files (an odd problem, at that).

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Let's say I have site collection "SC", and a custom content type "MyBaseType" defined at the SC level. Then, I have a subsite "SS" and have extended the content type to "MyExtendedType". This content type is stored at the subsite level, but it inherits fields from MyBaseType, which is at the SC level. If someone has contribute access across the SS subsite, including a list that uses MyExtendedType, they can see "Add new item" but get Access Denied when they click it. If I add them to the Visitors group for the site collection, no more errors.

Answer (score 1):

After I added my comment above, I realized something. For some reason, in order to access the custom content type defined at the site collection level, the user needs a specific permission. Here's what worked for me:

In Site Actions -> Site Permissions, click Permission Levels. Click Add a Permission Level and call it whatever you want (I called mine "Use Custom Content Types"). Then, under the Site Permissions heading, tick the box next to "Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container." *Note* this is more restrictive than Restricted Read or any other default permission sets.

Now go back to Site Permissions. You will probably want to create a group to encapsulate all groups/users that need this permission set. At the bottom of the Create Group dialog, tick the box next to "Use Custom Content Types" or whatever you called the permission set. Now you can add users and/or groups to this new Group to give them the ability to use the custom content types defined at the site collection level.

Give this a shot and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Just wanted to add an update. I just learned that if you grant a user access only to specific lists within a site collection, you could run into other issues. For example, one user tried to set an alert on a list they have contribute access to and received the Access Denied error. Though my solution above solves the custom content type problem, the Open permission is not sufficient for all cases. The best solution seems to be to grant Read permission at the site collection level.